# Visual Studio C# - SQLite.Interop.dll not found

Tags: c#, sqlite, dll, visual-studio-2015

I am currently trying to create with Visual Studio a C# application working with SQLite. I installed SQLite for my program with NuGet and three references appeared in the Solution Explorer (System.Data.SQLite, System.Data.SQLite.EF6, System.Data.SQLite.Linq).

When I execute my app in VS, everything works fine. However, whenever I publish it (with ClickOnce) and try to run the app, it crashes with the following error :
**System.DllNotFoundException : Unable to load DLL 'SQLite.Interop.dll' : the specified module cannot be found (Exception from HRESULT : 0x8007007E)**

After some research, I found this dll in the Debug folder and copied it in the folder where the ".exe" version of my program is created (after publishing and executing "setup.exe"). This way, the app runs well.

But I'm not really satisfied with this solution, since it seems really dirty. I don't want future users to have to do this manually when they install my app !

Therefore, my question is : What can I do to make sure that this dll is installed together with my program ?

*Note : I tried the first answer of this post :
[unable to load dll sqlite interop dll WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27678554/unable-to-load-dll-sqlite-interop-dll-wpf)
But I didn't seem to work for me.*

Comment: Duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13028069/unable-to-load-dll-sqlite-interop-dll?page=1

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See **Using Native Library Pre-Loading** at https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki

You likely need to include the x86 and x64 folders under the the other SQLite DLL.

Edit: I've added the relevant info below in case the above link ever dies/changes.

> If the development and customer machines may have different processor
>   architectures, more than one binary package may be required. For this
>   situation, using the native library pre-loading feature is highly
>   recommended. It is available as of version 1.0.80.0 and enabled by
>   default. In order to take advantage of this feature, the separate
>   managed and interop assemblies must be used with XCOPY deployment
>   (i.e. this feature is not supported by the mixed-mode assembly, nor
>   when the assembly is deployed to the global assembly cache), resulting
>   in an application deployment that looks something like this:

- bin\App.exe (optional, managed-only application executable
  assembly)
- bin\App.dll (optional, managed-only application library
  assembly)
- bin\System.Data.SQLite.dll (required, managed-only core
  assembly)
- bin\System.Data.SQLite.Linq.dll (optional, managed-only
  LINQ assembly)
- bin\System.Data.SQLite.EF6.dll (optional,
  managed-only EF6 assembly)
- bin\x86\SQLite.Interop.dll (required,
  x86 native interop assembly)
- bin\x64\SQLite.Interop.dll (required,
  x64 native interop assembly)

> The string "bin" above represents the directory where the application
>   binaries are to be deployed on the target machine. With the native
>   library pre-loading feature enabled and the application deployment
>   shown above, the System.Data.SQLite managed-only assembly will attempt
>   to automatically detect the processor architecture of the current
>   process and pre-load the appropriate native library.

Comment: Thank you for your help ! I included the dll file from the x86 folder as an Existing Element in my projet and set it to "Copy Always", and now it seems to work perfectly when I publish my app !

Comment: Worked for me.  Included NUGET packages "SQLite" and "System.Data.SQLite.Core" and then included folders bin\x86 and bin\x64 in project. Deployed without errors afterward. +1

Answer (score 14):

I also encountered the similar issue in my environment of Visual Studio 2017 and NET Framework 4.5, the circumstance is:

I am developing an Outlook Add Ins using ClickOnce to publish it and SQLite as the database. After having installed the SQLite library into the project from NuGet, it works perfectly in the local environment but pops up the exception error message "Unable to load DLL 'SQLite.Interop.dll'" on the client machine.

I compared the two environments and found the DLL file 'SQLite.Interop.dll' had not been published to the client machine that we can see in the following graphic.
[image]

I searched 'SQLite.Interop.dll' in local environment and found it is saved in the following folder "{project}\packages\System.Data.SQLite.Core.1.0.105.2\build\" for the specific .Net FrameWork
[image]

**So, my solution is adding these two DLL libraries into the project, then they can be published to the client machine using the ClickOnce.**
[image]

(Notice: The selected DLL version should be as same as the NET Framework version in your environment.)

Comment: Solution works with "copy always" parameter set for both dll. Thanks !

Comment: This is the best solution I've seen so far. It feels cleaner than adding the System.Data.Sqlite package to the main project. Still not pretty, but I think it's better. It should be an answer on [this more prominent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13028069) Q/A.

Answer (score 10):

Please use the answer to the duplicate issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60176344/3634867

Don't store the dll yourself and copy it to /bin manually, it will lost control to the version updating and dependency.

**TL;DR;**

> for old csproj file:
>
> ```
> <PropertyGroup> 
>     <ContentSQLiteInteropFiles>true</ContentSQLiteInteropFiles>
>     <CopySQLiteInteropFiles>false</CopySQLiteInteropFiles>
>     <CleanSQLiteInteropFiles>false</CleanSQLiteInteropFiles>
>     <CollectSQLiteInteropFiles>false</CollectSQLiteInteropFiles>
> </PropertyGroup>
> ```
>
> for new csporj file: (i.e. projects beginning with `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.*">`)
>
> ```
> <PackageReference Include="System.Data.SQLite.Core" Version="1.0.110" PrivateAssets="none"/>
> ```

Answer (score 7):

By default the dll sqlite.interop.dll does not come with NuGet installation of SQLite. To solve this you need to add both the dlls, x86 and x64.
At the SQLite website download the pack containing necessary dlls. Install them in client or copy these dlls to your Project before distributing.

Comment: it actually comes with the Nuget installation

Answer (score 2):

Upgrading the System.Data.SQLite.Core Nuget package to version 1.0.109.2 fixed the error for me.

Answer (score 1):

If it is an installable file. i.e, if u are creating setup file, then you have to add the dll manually to the primary output file.

Go to properties of the setup project and in configuration settings, select pre-requisites SQLLite, select(Checkbox) install it from the project location.

See if this solves your issue.

Comment: Thanks for your help ! Sadly enough, I cannot find SQLite in the list of pre-requisites, only SQL Server... Did I miss something ? (I'm quite new to VS, and my version is in French, which doesn't really help to look for menus)

Answer (score 1):

"Note : I tried the first answer of this post : unable to load dll sqlite interop dll WPF But I didn't seem to work for me."

I tried that, too, and finally got it working. However, important is:

1. Insert the sqlite.interop.dll as an existing item to the root of the project you are going to build.
2. In the properties of that file, make sure its build processing is 'content' (not embedded resource as suggested) and, of course, copied to the output directory always.

Hope that helps to beat that annoying bug.

Answer (score 1):

The System.Data.SQLite nuget package includes a Build folder with a targets file that will copy these interop dlls. To solve this, we had to tell the project we were packaging into our own nuget, to NOT exclude this build target/folder.

Our project (the one we package and then use elsewhere) needed to have PrivateAssets="None" or PrivateAssets="Analyzers" if you want to make sure not to include Analyzers.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild>True</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
    <RootNamespace>MyNamespace</RootNamespace>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="ServiceStack.OrmLite.Sqlite.Core" Version="5.6.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Data.SQLite.Core" Version="1.0.111"  PrivateAssets="Analyzers" />
   </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Answer (score 1):

SQlite.Interop is not referenceable, you have to:

> 1. In your VS project Add Existing File: Sqlite.Interop.dll actual
>      location is .\bin\Debug\x86 or \bin\Debug\x64
> 2. Select properties and set Compilation Action in "Content" and copy
>      to the output directory = "Always Copy"
> 3. Rebuild

Answer (score 0):

One alternative solution might be to replace the *xcopy post build* by using the *System.Data.SQLite.Core.targets* script file from the *System.Data.SQLite.Core* package for doing that.
Here my working *csproj* file:
[image]