# System.Data.SQLite dll Not Found When Running a WPF as an UWP

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite, uwp

I'm planning to publish my WPF application to Microsoft Store.
So I follow this [LINK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-packaging-dot-net) to package my app.

In accessing **SQLite** db, I'm using **System.Data.SQLite** lib developed by SQLite Dev team.

When I execute my app as WPF everything normal, but when I execute my app as UWP it throws error:

```
System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'SQLite.Interop.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
at System.Data.SQLite.UnsafeNativeMethods.sqlite3_config_none(SQLiteConfigOpsEnum op)
at System.Data.SQLite.SQLite3.StaticIsInitialized()
at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteLog.Initialize(String className)
at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection..ctor(String connectionString, Boolean parseViaFramework)
at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection..ctor(String connectionString)
at eComEasy.Lib.Helper.LibUtility.InitiateDbSchema(String connString, String[] names)
```

How can I fix this?

Note: I manage to create the db file, but when I wanna create teble, the above error came up.

Comment: Is there some additional information inside the exception? Like inner exception?

Comment: No or I just cant find it..

Comment: Did you remember to deploy the dll with the application? Despite the name, `System.Data.SQLite` is *not* part of .NET. A UWP has to include any dlls it needs in its package

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I checked in bin/AnyCPU/Debug/AppX/myapp and all dlls are there

Comment: @MartinZikmund I just updated the ERROR message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to reference the `System.Data.SQLite` package from NuGet:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Data.SQLite -Version 2.1.0
```

Or using **NuGet Package Manager UI** in Visual Studio (right-click the project, choose **Manage NuGet Packages for Solution...** and search for `Microsoft.Data.SQLite`.

In case it does not help try following the **Using Native Library Preloading** section [in the SQLite docs](https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki), although I wouldn't expect that to be necessary.

Comment: I do not plan to move from System.Data.SQLite to Microsoft.Data.SQLite yet ... too many classes use this lib. Maybe after I gave up

Answer (score 0):

At last, I can make it works after following this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38594837/visual-studio-c-sharp-sqlite-interop-dll-not-found). Where all I can do is create 2 folders of x86 and x64, add SQLite.Interop.dll and set it to Copy Always.
Even thou I'm not sure whether this can be distributes through Microsoft Store. I still need to investigate.

Comment: That is the alternative solution I have mentioned in my answer