# Unable to load SQLite.Interop.dll C#

Tags: c#, sqlite, exception, .net-4.0, system.data.sqlite

I am working on a project using SQLite - getting above error when trying to open the Connection, using SQLite for the first time.

Followed below links **amongst** others but error still persists - any pointers appreciated

[Visual Studio C# - SQLite.Interop.dll not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38594837/visual-studio-c-sharp-sqlite-interop-dll-not-found?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[Unable to load DLL 'SQLite.Interop.dll'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13028069/unable-to-load-dll-sqlite-interop-dll)

Package.config

```
<packages>
<package id="EntityFramework" version="6.4.4" targetFramework="net471"/>
<package id="System.Data.SQLite" version="1.0.112.2"targetFramework="net471" />
<package id="System.Data.SQLite.Core" version="1.0.112.2"targetFramework="net471" />
<package id="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" version="1.0.112.2"targetFramework="net471" />
<package id="System.Data.SQLite.Linq" version="1.0.112.2"targetFramework="net471" />
</packages>
```

Now getting below Error:-
[image: BadImageFormatException]

It's any CPU

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your post-build step is wrong, I think. You should copy the folder `x86`, not only its contents. Also, since presumably your application runs in 64 bit mode, you also need to copy the `x64` folder. So in the end, you have two folders `x86` and `x64` below the folder with your main executable, both of them containing a file called `SQLite.interop.dll`.

Comment: I will try that and see if that fixes the problem

Comment: Amended the post0build step to include x64 but same error persists

Comment: That is weird. What exact target framework are you using?

Comment: .NET Framework 4.7.1

Comment: I'm using version 1.0.115 and .NET 4.8, but otherwise this works for me. Are you sure the working directory of your application is correct?

Comment: It is correct - this is really driving me crazy!

Comment: Have you tried checking whether there's really a dependency issue with the dll? Use a tool such as https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies/releases/tag/v1.11.1 to check for dependeny problems.

Comment: used the tool and got it to work - then found out I have to use an older version - now getting BadImageFormatException - uploaded in main post

Comment: That is typically the result of trying to load a 32 bit dll into a 64 bit process or vice-versa. Is your application 32 bit, 64 bit or AnyCpu?

Comment: it's any CPU - updated post with new package.config pointing to older version

Comment: Try whether you get it to run if you set it explicitly to 32 or 64 bit. If either of them works, you should get a hint on what could be wrong.

Comment: Tried all 3 and same error

Comment: It could be that the dll's are corrupted